# rchart nvd3 - set tickmark interval

Tags: r, nvd3.js, rcharts

I'd like to specify the interval on the xAxis of a lineChart in rchart nvd3 to be 1.

Currently I have a dynamic chart that has the xAxis being either 0-6, 0-5, or 0-3 - when xAxis only ranges from 0-3, the tickmark interval automatically becomes 0.5, but in this case doesn't make sense, and I would like it to still go by integer intervals - how do I specify that?

Currently my code looks like:

```
p <- nPlot(   yvalue ~ xvalue,   data = dat,   group = "scenario_id",  type = "lineChart" )

p$yAxis(tickFormat = "#!
        function(d) {return d3.format('%')(d)}
        !#" )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to manually set the tick values by doing:

```
p$xAxis(tickValues=min(dat$xvalue):max(dat$xvalue))
```